# Deleting a file in Laravel cause an exception

Tags: laravel, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file in `Laravel` but it is causing this exception:

```
unlink(D:\graduation project\kh\storage\app\upload/three.zip): Resource temporarily unavailable in D:\graduation project\kh\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php
```

before trying to delete the file i checked if it exists, checking returned a true value.
here is my piece of code in the controller:

```
protected function saveFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $zip = new Zipper;
        $fileName = $this->createFilename($file);

        $finalPath = storage_path().'/app/upload/';

        // move the file name
        $file->move($finalPath, $fileName);
        $zip->make($finalPath.$fileName)->extractTo($finalPath);
        $exist = Storage::disk('local')->exists('/upload/'.$fileName);
        if($exist){
           Storage::delete('/upload/'.$fileName) //I get the error here; 
        }

        return response()->json([
            'path' => $finalPath,
            'name' => $fileName,
            'exist' => $exist
        ]);
    }
```

and this is the response I get. It shows that the file exists (Note: when I took this image I commented the deletion line): [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eayD.png)

Comment: You probably need to close the opened zip before you can delete it

Comment: That's right! , thank you